# D - properties with two arguments

Tags: d

D's language [reference](http://dlang.org/spec/function.html#property-functions) states that

> @property functions can only have zero, one or two parameters.

It's quite clear what properties with zero and one parameter do, and there's an example for each in the reference. However, the reference doesn't say anything about two-parameter properties, apart of the fact that they are allowed. So, what do they actually do? What do the parameters for such a property mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A property with two parameters would be a UFCS setter. Suppose we had:

```
struct Whatever {
   void setProperty(int);
}
```

And you wanted to add a property setter instead of calling setProperty, but can't change the struct itself for whatever reason. You might add an outside function like this:

```
@property int my_prop(ref Whatever _this, int prop_value) {
       _this.setProperty(prop_value);
       return prop_value;
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
Whatever w;
w.my_prop = 10;
```

So the first param is the extension `this` and the second param is the traditional setting value.